# adding 2 separate numbers to an array

Tags: c#

Sorry this may a dumb question, I am learning c# in school and have came up with a dice roller program. 
The issue that I am having is instead of gathering the total of the 2 dice that are rolled then placing it into an array the instructor wants us to get the number of each die in a pair and then compare it against the second pair of die rolls. I have the rolls set up but I am not sure on how to get each number of die into the array. Here is the code that I have so far. Not looking for the answer just a point in the right direction.

Here is my code (inside a `Button` click event handler of a `Form`):

```
Random roll = new Random();
int [,] dieValue1 = new int[7, 7];
int[,] dieValue2 = new int[7, 7];
int die1 = 0;
int die2 = 0;
int die3 = 0;
int die4 = 0;
die1 = roll.Next(6);
die2 = roll.Next(6);
die3 = roll.Next(6);
die4 = roll.Next(6);
lblDice1.ImageIndex = die1;
lblDice2.ImageIndex = die2;
//die roll for the first list
for (int rollNum = 1; rollNum< 51; rollNum++)
{
    die1 = roll.Next(1, 7);
    die2 = roll.Next(1, 7);
    dieValue1[die1, die2] += 1; 
    lstRolls.Items.Add("Roll " + rollNum + " : " + "die 1 is a " + die1 + ", " + "die 2 is a " + die2);
}
//die roll for the second list 
for (int rollNum1 = 1; rollNum1< 51; rollNum1++)
{                
    die3 = roll.Next(1, 7);
    die4 = roll.Next(1, 7);
    dieValue2[die3, die4] += 1;
    lstRolls2.Items.Add("Roll " + rollNum1 + " : " + "die 3 is a " + die3 + ", " + "die 4 is a " + die4);
}
for (int r = 1; r < 51; r++)
{
    lstRollDifference.Items.Add("First rolls :" + dieValue1 + " " + "Second rolls :" + dieValue2);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused - so you have a running total of the number of times that each number combination is rolled, and now you're trying to keep track of each individual roll? What do you mean by rolling them in a pair and comparing it against the second dice roll?

Comment: I am keeping track of two separate pairs of dice that each pair is rolling 50 times. He wanted the numbers of each pair displayed. I did that 2 separate list boxes. But now he is stating that he wants the 2 pairs of dice compared against one another. I will be using a IEnumerable.Comparer to compare the two pairs of dice rolled 50 times .EX. Pair 1 {6,3} Pair2 {1,4} then i have to go through and using IEnumerable sift through the 50 roles of each pair and display for example pair 1 has {2,1} which pair 2 does not.

Comment: The simplest view is to make each array 1 dimensional where the index is the roll number; for 50 rolls: `int[] die1Values = new int[50];`, `int[] die2Values = new int[50];`; for each roll: `die1Values[rollNum] = (result of rolling die 1)`, `die2Values[rollNum] = (result of rolling die 2)`. Instead of implicit coupling you can combine them into a single 2D array: `int[,] allDieValues = new int[2, 50]`; with this data structure you can do: `allDieValues[0][rollNum] = (die 1 result)`, `allDieValues[1][rollNum] = (die 2 result)`, where the 1st dimension is the # of dice, and 2nd is # of rolls.

Comment: Have you studied LINQ yet?

Comment: We are just starting it with this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to keep your int arrays, you can convert your int arrays to objects of type:

```
public class Pair 
{
   public int FirstDie { get; set; }
   public int SecondDie { get; set; }
}
```

Then convert your array for each player to a list of the `Pair` type like this:

```
public static List<Pair> ConvertToPairs(int[,] dieValues) 
{
   var query = from int item in dieValues
               select item;

   var p1Rolls = query.ToList();
   List<Pair> pairs = new List<Pair>( p1Rolls.Count );
   for( int i = 0; i < 4; i += 2 ) 
   {
      pairs.Add( new Pair() { FirstDie = p1Rolls[ i ], SecondDie = p1Rolls[ i + 1 ] } );
   }

   return pairs;
}
```

Then you can user `Except` for player1's rolls vs player2's rolls to get the difference. Here is how you would do so for player 1. I will let you figure out player 2. I have 2 rolls in this example program.

```
class Program 
{
   static void Main(string[] args) 
   {

      int[,] dieValue1 = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
      int[,] dieValue2 = { { 1, 2 }, { 6, 4 } };



      var p1Rolls = ConvertToPairs( dieValue1 );
      var p2Rolls = ConvertToPairs( dieValue2 );

      foreach( var item in p1Rolls.Except( p2Rolls ) ) 
      {

         Console.WriteLine( "Player 1 has [{0}, {1}] which player 2 does not.", item.FirstDie, item.SecondDie );
      }

      var result = LoadComment( 1, null );
      Console.ReadKey();

   }

   public static List<Pair> ConvertToPairs(int[,] dieValues) 
   {
      var query = from int item in dieValues
                  select item;

      var p1Rolls = query.ToList();
      List<Pair> pairs = new List<Pair>( p1Rolls.Count );
      for( int i = 0; i < 4; i += 2 ) 
      {
         pairs.Add( new Pair() { FirstDie = p1Rolls[ i ], SecondDie = p1Rolls[ i + 1 ] } );
      }

      return pairs;
   }
}
```

Please note you can just use this `Pair` construct to start with and every time you roll you will create one of these for each player. This way you do not need all those arrays you have.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input to help me with this. I appreciate your patience with me being such a noob. I hope that one day i can return the favor to you all.

Answer (score -1):

Store the dice roll as a new object.  Produce a DiceRoll class that stores a pair of dice, and has functions for ToString, Total  and to compare one DiceRoll to another.  You could even have a default constructor that contains your randomizer, or a constructor that takes the roll pair generated elsewhere.  Put your DiceRoll objects into a list (which is IEnumerable).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx